# Does wood oil stop woodworm ingress?

Tags: wood, protection, insect

I have a can of wood oil branded "Osmo TopOil". It makes no claim about any resistance to woodboring insects, and having used it before, I thought the coating was fairly subtle and not very thick. However, as it is a mix of oils and waxes, I feel like that ought to stop unwanted beasties laying their eggs.

The full ingredients say:

> Based on natural plant oils and waxes (sunflower oil, soya oil, thistle oil, carnauba wax and candelilla wax), paraffin, pigments, lead-free siccatives (drying agents) and water-repellent additives. Dearomatized white spirit (benzene-free).

In general, are wood oils like this sufficient to stop ingress of furniture beetles, or do I need something more definite like varnish or paint? I cannot find any answer online.

Comment: I do not know, but imagine it would make the wood less tasty than plain wood.  More like resistance than stopping them completely.  You have the can.  If you like how it looks on wood, I would say have fun.

Comment: The people over at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/  might have better ideas.

Comment: I doubt that it would stop them. I have a painted post on my front porch that was invaded by a wood boring critter of some sort. I've got the critters killed and now need to plug up the hole they left.

Comment: It would probably also need a good coat on all sides. Imagine building only three sides of a boat... It'll sink :)